# Shell Scripting: Filter text & append in a variable

Tags: shell

I need shell command to do the following:

INPUT:

```
  "M       ABC/PQR/src/MyFile.h"
```

OUTPUT:

```
  "ABC/PQR/src/MyFile.h"
```

Comment: I guess we need more explanation, as well as some code you tried.

Comment: I just need to remove `M` & the space after that till the start of the actual file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to print the second block of text, this will work:

```
echo "\"M       ABC/PQR/src/MyFile.h\"" | awk '{print $2}'
```

To challenge us using `sed` options, this will also work:

```
echo "\"M       ABC/PQR/src/MyFile.h\"" | sed 's/M[ ]*//'
```

I see a comment by @Fredrik Pihl indicating that quotes `"` should be preserved. In that case, the second version will work.

Comment: and you need to use `$ echo \"M       ABC/PQR/src/MyFile.h\"` in you test, or else the quotes will not be present

Comment: You are right, @FredrikPihl. It was not clear from the OP but now I was testing on my computer with this `\"`. Just updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: no need for the global flag to sed or a character class for a single space, simply use `sed 's/M *//'`

Comment: Yes, as it is just one repetition. Just to learn: does adding `g` affect the performance of `sed`? Is it slower or has any bad consequence?

Comment: `g` means do the substitution for all occurences of the pattern, so yes it's slower. without it, sed stops after the first match. IRL it shouldn't really matter if the lines are not really huge

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I will update my answer to make it better and not use unnecessary parameters.